# How to use the library opencv on android with a newly created photo?

Tags: android, opencv

I would like to help me. I am new to android, want to use OpenCV to detect yellow color images in images already created by a photo, I mean, from a photo created, becomes a bitmap, and make a searching if there is yellow in the picture, and the next layout showing the image with the filter.

Unfiltered photo ->  photo with filter